# AWRPC Token (CRM Dynamics) and JMeter

Tags: jmeter, token, crm, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-2015

i'm trying to script a scenario in CRM dynamics using jmeter.

1. the main.aspx generated awprc tokens for use with further requests made by other (web)services in crm, such as;

`_aWrpcTokens['\x2fVEH\x2fAPPWEBSERVICES\x2fRECENTLYVIEWEDWEBSERVICE.ASMX']={Token: '5ZqnYysbEeeA6gBQVpxYnwkYlUcIWHa0JWMJtmBDIkwZyiV\x2fK0NSb6F6hk9A1ZlT', Timestamp: "636310419198725996"};
_aWrpcTokens['\x2fVEH\x2fAPPWEBSERVICES\x2fLOOKUPMRUWEBSERVICE.ASMX']={Token: '5ZqnYysbEeeA6gBQVpxYn3eC\x2fEZXZ6r9iAxsyhDxcpth6OF7TBmFH\x2b3Ou9OKvX8k', Timestamp: "636310419198725996"};
_aWrpcTokens['\x2fVEH\x2fAPPWEBSERVICES\x2fMESSAGEBAR.ASMX']={Token: '5ZqnYysbEeeA6gBQVpxYn5X70v4ruaTNpxnKJZlYT84W1iutepmMFXTA8fhDdYxh', Timestamp: "636310419198725996"};
_aWrpcTokens['\x2fVEH\x2fAPPWEBSERVICES\x2fLOOKUPSERVICE.ASMX']={Token: '5ZqnYysbEeeA6gBQVpxYn\x2b0bSqvJ\x2fxc2Q8H3A7B55FhJPVopqiTNSqLlKEyZDOTy', Timestamp: "636310419198725996"};
_aWrpcTokens['\x2fVEH\x2fAPPWEBSERVICES\x2fSCRIPTERROR.ASMX']={Token: '5ZqnYysbEeeA6gBQVpxYnweJlDnx6biwmhKg4EGQyTUo7qqUSv\x2b1Eo90DeJXLytL', Timestamp: "636310419198725996"};`

In the case of for example, RECENTLYVIEWEDWEBSERVICE.ASMX, the token generated is: `5ZqnYysbEeeA6gBQVpxYnwkYlUcIWHa0JWMJtmBDIkwZyiV\x2fK0NSb6F6hk9A1ZlT`

.. but when i inspect what this service POST's in the header it looks like the last part of the token is re encoded with *some* encoding which i cannot figure out. I have seen implementations where i'd only had to replace specific characters such as \ and + etc but this looks quite different.

generated: `5ZqnYysbEeeA6gBQVpxYnwkYlUcIWHa0JWMJtmBDIkwZyiV\x2fK0NSb6F6hk9A1ZlT`

post'ed:`5ZqnYysbEeeA6gBQVpxYn1AODXVDsrilvonK6nxRNB9oBkgxDhOXjgINDkEVusHB`

Q: What is happening to the last part of the token after 5ZqnYysbEeeA6gBQVpxYn... ? Is it possible to use the same type of encoding in JMeter using beanshell/jsr etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Key management in Microsoft Dynamics CRM](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh699824(v=crm.6).aspx) article:

> Key regeneration and renewal
>
> CRM ticket keys are automatically generated and renewed and then distributed, or deployed, to all computers running Microsoft Dynamics CRM or running a specific Microsoft Dynamics CRM Server 2013 role. These keys are regenerated periodically and, in turn, replace the previous keys. **By default, key regeneration occurs every 24 hours**.

So make sure your record and replay happens within 24 hours time frame.

Alternatively you can ask your CRM administrator to [temorarily disable this token check](https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/57032ef6-c690-4ab2-a7e1-21f1081e5350/can-not-mark-crm-2011-appointments-as-complete?forum=crmdevelopment) by changing value (or creating) of the following registry key to 1:

```
HKLM>Software>Microsoft>MSCRM>IgnoreTokenCheck (Dword)=1
```

Check out [How to Load Test CSRF-Protected Web Sites](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-csrf-protected-web-sites) article for more information on load testing [XSRF protected applications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) with JMeter

Comment: Hey Dmitri, thanks for the comment. As for the awprc tokens this does not apply i'm afraid, because on each browser refresh the tokens are re-generated for each subsqeuent service within main.aspx. 

I came across the registry workaround, gonna try that asap.